# What does "bagel girl" mean in tennis?

Tags: terminology, tennis

I encountered term *[bagel girl](http://www.google.com/search?q=bagel+girl+tennis)* in connection with a tennis player. I understood approximately the meaning of this term from the context, but could some clarify it in more detail? Is there also male equivalent for this colloquial term?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Bagel girl" is a derogatory term for a woman who frequently loses tennis sets 6-0. The stereotypical bagel girl is a young woman from a wealthy family who has enough money to keep traveling the world and entering professional tournaments, even though she has no chance of winning at that level.

The term comes from both the fact that a bagel is shaped like a zero and from a racial stereotype.

I'm not aware of a male equivalent of this term.

Comment: I have heard the term bagel used in other sports besides tennis.  For example sometimes an NBA player is said to have gotten a bagel if he scores 0 points in a game.

Comment: One thing that confuses me a little about this is that AFAIK player needs sufficient ranking to enter a tournament. (The players are selected for the spots in the main/qualifying draw based on their rankings.) So it does not suffice simply to have enough money, they still have to be high enough in WTA ranking.

Comment: @Martin Right, for a player who has trouble winning, it would more likely be ITA professional tournaments than WTA tournaments.  I've tweaked my answer.